# Allowing a function to accept an array or a string in Flow

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I have a function that can accept an array or a string:

```
/* @flow */
type Product = Array<string> | string

function printProducts(product: Product) {
    if (product.constructor === 'array') {
        product.map(p => console.log(p))
    } else {
        console.log(product)
    }
}
```

Flow complains "property `Map` not found in String".  How can I change my type definition to satisfy this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use one of the supported [dynamic type tests](https://flowtype.org/docs/dynamic-type-tests.html#typeof), in this case [`Array.isArray`](https://flowtype.org/docs/dynamic-type-tests.html#arrayisarray):

```
/* @flow */
type Product = Array<string> | string

function printProducts(product: Product) {
    if (Array.isArray(product)) {
        product.map(p => console.log(p))
    } else {
        console.log(product)
    }
}
```